# Initializing a multiobject deque<vector<vector<float> > >

Tags: c++, vector, initialization, deque, complextype

I have this c++ structure

```
std::deque<vector<vector<float> > > mydeque;
```

which I want to initialize with the following line of code:

```
mydeque(10, vector<vector<float> >(20,vector<float>(5,0.0f)));
```

to create a deque of 10 vectors each with 20 elements that are vectors of length 5 with 0.0f values.

I have this error:

```
error: no match for call to ‘(std::deque<std::vector<std::vector<float> > >) (int, std::vector<std::vector<float> >)’
```

Do you know how to fix this as I don't understand the error?
Also, can I skip some depth of the initialization, like the specification of the `vector<float>(5,0.0f)`?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you trying to do this in a constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot construct an object in two pass: the arguments must be given to the class constructor when the object is defined. This [works like a charm (demo)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3f8c563dda9b8eef):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <deque>

int main()
{
    std::deque<std::vector<std::vector<float>>> mydeque(10, std::vector<std::vector<float>>(20, std::vector<float>(5, .0f)));
}
```

Alternatively, you could define a custom constructor to help with readability:

```
template<typename T>
struct MyDeque : std::deque<std::vector<std::vector<T>>>
{
    MyDeque(size_t d1, size_t d2, size_t d3, const T& value = T())
        : std::deque<std::vector<std::vector<T>>>(d1, std::vector<std::vector<T>>(d2, std::vector<T>(d3, value)))
    {}
};

int main()
{
    MyDeque<float> mydeque(10, 20, 5, .0f);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't initialize a variable after it has been defined.  You need to either combine the two lines you have into one, or use the `assign` method of `deque`.

```
std::deque<vector<vector<float>>> mydeque(10, vector<vector<float>>(20, vector<float>(5,0.0f)));
```

or

```
mydeque.assign(10, vector<vector<float>>(20, vector<float>(5,0.0f)));
```